# Typescript react properties and methods modifiers

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Are there any recommended best practices for defining visibility modifiers within statefull react components ? For example, what modifiers should state ( as a class property, not defined inside constructor ) have inside a class ? What about methods ?

Answer (score 0):

State Access modifier inside a React Component can be either public or protected but because it's an inherited attribute from React.Component you have to follow the typing file you use in TypeScript. There is more than one project for providing typing for React but most of them use public for props and state.
I would suggest having a class definition for your props and state then use them inside your component.

```
export class StudentProps{
public Name:string;
public Id:number;
}
export class StudentState{
public CoursesNames:Array<string>;
}

export class Student extends React.Component{
 public props:StudentProps;
public state:StudentState;
}
```